# Get list of all city/place names in a country using Nominatim/OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, nominatim

I have set my own OpenStreetMap server (database is PostGis) and I'm using Nominatim for geo-coding and conversions from address to coordinate or coordinates to addresses. I need to get a list of all place names (cities, towns, villages etc.) from a country, but I still have trouble with understanding the DB structure. Any ideas how to do that?

I know there are other solutions (GeoNames or other available databases), please understand that I do not want to use them and I need to do this just by using OSM database and/or Nominatim database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download the OSM data you are interested in and load it to PostGIS using osm2pgsql. (not sure if you have already done this)

Then you just run the query:

```
  select name from planet_osm_point where place in ('city','town','village');
```

The data is not guaranteed to be complete off course, because the labelling is done in a crowd-sourced way.

Comment: Yes, I already used osm2pgsql. How to limit the results to a single country?

Comment: You can download OSM data for a single country from http://download.geofabrik.de/

Comment: Alternatively you can find the shapefiles for the country or region you want to find the cities for (OSM definitely has that), load them as geometry types in Postgis and then do an ST_Intersects(region,way) (way is the geometry in planet_osm_point).

Comment: That is not the easy way I hoped it exists. I will check Nominatim database maybe I can get something from it. If not yes, load boundries and ST_Intersects(region,way) is the best solution.

Comment: Just curious, why doesn't geofabrik.de work for you?

Comment: Because I already have osm2pgsql and Nominatim installation and I don't want to download and install whole OSM data again just to get a list of cities